# JSP class not found exception

Tags: jsp, tomcat, red5

I am trying to run a war file in Red5 0.9.0 server with embedded tomcat-6.0.24.

After deployment of WAR file I can access the index page sucessfully. But when I try to access any other jsp page, system throws error like:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.form.loginMai
>   n_jsp$Helper

I have searched in Work folder, I can find the class at:

> [red5- home]\work\red5Engine\0.0.0.0\myApp\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\pages\form\loginMain_jsp$Helper.class

I cannot understand why tomcat cannot find this jsp class. Please help.

Here is the full stacktrace of error:

```
[ERROR] [http-0.0.0.0-5080-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[red5Engine ].[0.0.0.0].[/myApp].[jsp] - Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.form.loginMai n_jsp$Helper
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) [na:1.7.0_40]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) [na:1.7.0_40]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_ 40]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) [na:1.7.0_ 40]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:13 4) [jasper-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66 ) [jasper-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_40]

        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2483) [na:1 .7.0_40]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2793) [na:1.7.0_40]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:345) [na:1.7.0_40]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrap per.java:145) [jasper-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspSer vletWrapper.java:480) [jasper-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper .java:338) [jasper-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:3 13) [jasper-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260) [ja sper-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) [javaee- api-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl icationFilterChain.java:290) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF ilterChain.java:206) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDisp atcher.java:646) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(Applica tionDispatcher.java:436) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationD ispatcher.java:374) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDis patcher.java:302) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMerge dOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:239) [spring-webmvc-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0 .0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView .java:250) [spring-webmvc-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherSe rvlet.java:1060) [spring-webmvc-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(Dispatch erServlet.java:798) [spring-webmvc-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(Dispatche rServlet.java:716) [spring-webmvc-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(Frame workServlet.java:647) [spring-webmvc-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServl et.java:552) [spring-webmvc-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617) [javaee- api-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) [javaee- api-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl icationFilterChain.java:290) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF ilterChain.java:206) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.red5.logging.LoggerContextFilter.doFilter(LoggerContextFilter.jav a:87) [red5.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl icationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF ilterChain.java:206) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterIntern al(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerR equestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl icationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF ilterChain.java:206) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV alve.java:233) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV alve.java:191) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica torBase.java:465) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j ava:127) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j ava:102) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java: 555) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal ve.java:109) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav a:298) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java :852) [tomcat-coyote-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.proce ss(Http11Protocol.java:588) [tomcat-coyote-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:48 9) [tomcat-coyote-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [na:1.7.0_40] [ERROR] [http-0.0.0.0-5080-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[red5Engine ].[0.0.0.0].[/myApp].[myApp] - Servlet.service() for servlet myApp threw excepti on java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.form.loginMai n_jsp$Helper
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) [na:1.7.0_40]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) [na:1.7.0_40]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_ 40]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) [na:1.7.0_ 40]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:13 4) [jasper-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66 ) [jasper-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_40]

        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2483) [na:1 .7.0_40]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2793) [na:1.7.0_40]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:345) [na:1.7.0_40]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrap per.java:145) [jasper-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspSer vletWrapper.java:480) [jasper-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper .java:338) [jasper-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:3 13) [jasper-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260) [ja sper-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) [javaee- api-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl icationFilterChain.java:290) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF ilterChain.java:206) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDisp atcher.java:646) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(Applica tionDispatcher.java:436) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationD ispatcher.java:374) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDis patcher.java:302) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMerge dOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:239) [spring-webmvc-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0 .0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView .java:250) [spring-webmvc-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherSe rvlet.java:1060) [spring-webmvc-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(Dispatch erServlet.java:798) [spring-webmvc-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(Dispatche rServlet.java:716) [spring-webmvc-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(Frame workServlet.java:647) [spring-webmvc-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServl et.java:552) [spring-webmvc-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617) [javaee- api-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) [javaee- api-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl icationFilterChain.java:290) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF ilterChain.java:206) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.red5.logging.LoggerContextFilter.doFilter(LoggerContextFilter.jav a:87) [red5.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl icationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF ilterChain.java:206) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterIntern al(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerR equestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl icationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF ilterChain.java:206) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV alve.java:233) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV alve.java:191) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica torBase.java:465) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j ava:127) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j ava:102) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java: 555) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal ve.java:109) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav a:298) [catalina-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java :852) [tomcat-coyote-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.proce ss(Http11Protocol.java:588) [tomcat-coyote-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:48 9) [tomcat-coyote-6.0.24.jar:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [na:1.7.0_40]
```

Comment: After many tries I could not find the exact solutions. I suspect it is because of some security issue so it did not allow my files to convert in class files. I found some .classtmp files in my work folder and at last I have manually changed them to .class and it worked! Though it is not a good solution but it worked for me. :)

Comment: It would be a good idea to post this as an answer so that it can help future visitors. It helped me, and if it were an answer I would have upvoted it.

Answer (score -1):

After many tries I could not find the exact solutions. I suspect it is because of some security issue so it did not allow my files to convert in class files. I found some .classtmp files in my work folder and at last I have manually changed them to .class and it worked! Though it is not a good solution but it worked for me. :)

Answer (score -2):

Try removing your application folders in `$TOMCAT_HOME/work/localhost/catalina` and also in the config folder and restart tomcat.

Comment: I tried this but it did not worked. Please check my comments on this. BTW thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Glad you found a solution :)